# Create dynamic table with api data

Tags: php, html, api

**How do I make my table dynamically list all the values it pulls from the api, atm it only pulls 1 record and puts it in the table, the rest of the data gets put outside it**

Probably something very small I'm missing here, but can't put my finger on it

Thanks for any help, very appreciated.

```
<?php
$trackingId = $_POST['trackingId'];
if (isset($_POST['trackingId'])) {
    $fetch = json_decode(file_get_contents(sprintf('apigoeshere', $trackingId)));
    if ($fetch->status != 'OK') {
        echo sprintf('Error: %s', $fetch->message);
    } else {
        //example how to access statistics variable
        $inactiveAccounts = $fetch->statistics->inactiveAccounts;
        echo sprintf('Inactive accounts: %d' . "<br /><br />", $inactiveAccounts);
?>
<table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Account name</th>
            <th>Level</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
            //example how to display all accounts username
            foreach ($fetch->accounts as $account) {
     ?>
        <tr>
                <td><?php
                echo $account->username;
        ?></td>
            <td><?php
            echo $account->currentLevel;
        ?></td>
       </tr>
</table>
    <?php
        }
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you just do `echo count($fetch->accounts);` to see what is the `length` of the `array` returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didnt close foreach in right place. use this code instead

```
<?php
$trackingId = $_POST['trackingId'];
if (isset($_POST['trackingId'])) {

    $fetch = json_decode(file_get_contents(sprintf('apigoeshere', $trackingId)));

    if ($fetch->status != 'OK') {
        echo sprintf('Error: %s', $fetch->message);
    } else {
        //example how to access statistics variable
        $inactiveAccounts = $fetch->statistics->inactiveAccounts;
        echo sprintf('Inactive accounts: %d' . "<br /><br />", $inactiveAccounts);
?>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Account name</th>
        <th>Level</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        //example how to display all accounts username
        foreach ($fetch->accounts as $account) {
?>
   <tr>
        <td><?php
            echo $account->username;
?></td>
        <td><?php
            echo $account->currentLevel;
?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
            }
    ?>
</table>
<?php

    }
}
?>
```